# phpunit with composer not working

Tags: php, ubuntu, composer-php, vagrant

Background: i am on a windows host and sshing into a vagrant LAMP setup (ubuntu 13.04).

I have installed phpunit with composer using the following line in my composer.json:

```
"require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
}
```

I have then run composer update which installed phpunit. I can now navigate to /vendor/bin and see phpunit binary.

However if i type phpunit from within that directory (or anywhere elese for that matter) I get the error "phpunit is not installed"

Any suggestions as to where I go next with this - there are so few steps involved in this setup I really cant see where I could have gone wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`./phpunit` from the `bin` directory.

It's just not in your path.

Comment: Dang I wish the downvoter would explain why the downvote.  Here's a full illustration of the problem and the solution: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20304987/terminal.html jerkwad ;)

Comment: +1 I think you are (almost) right. When I follow your instruction I get a permission denied message (despite being the owner of the file) when I run it with sudo I get 'command not found'. Any suggestions?

Comment: `if [ -x "phpunit" ]; then echo "executable"; else echo "not executable"; fi` tests if it's executable.  `ls -la` will also tell you who can execute the file, if anyone.  `chmod a+x phpunit` makes it executable by everyone.  That's all the bash help you get for a PHP question :)

Answer (score 5):

So I had this issue too, for me the fix was to change in my vagrant file:

`config.vm.synced_folder "C:/dev/vm/share", "/var/www/", mount_options: ['dmode=777','fmode=666']`

to

`config.vm.synced_folder "C:/dev/vm/share", "/var/www/", mount_options: ['dmode=777','fmode=777']`

There is a lot of advise saying 666 is permissive enough, but in my case it was not and as this is only a development machine the security implications are not too important.

Comment: fmode=766 is not quite as permissive but sufficient to run phpunit.

Answer (score 0):

I created the script above:

```
#!/bin/bash
binary=$1
shift
dir=$PWD
for i in $( seq 5 )
do
 if [ -e "$dir/composer.json" ]
 then
  $dir/vendor/bin/$binary $@
 else
  echo "not found phpunit in $dir"
 fi 
  dir="$dir/.."
done
```

If you name it 'composer.exec', and put it n your path, you can call it:

```
composer.exec phpunit [phpunit-options]
```

And there is it! Calling phpunit or any other bin contained in vendor/bin.